# The `AllInstances` using in the `MS Fakes`

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

MS Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.
.Net Framework 4.6

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx):

> To use a shim for an instance method, write `AllInstances` between the
>   type name and the method name:
>
> ```
> System.IO.Fakes.ShimFile.AllInstances.ReadToEnd = ...
> ```

But when I write `.` after `ShimFile` the *IntelliSense* does not have an `AllInstances` item in the ComboBox:

[image]

[image]

Also I try to do the same for `DateTime` and I see another problem: the `AllInstances` exists, but the *IntelliSense* does not have items for it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why do these errors occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For issue number 1, I think you're trying to use the wrong Shim class.  You want StreamReader (which contains the `ReadToEnd` method).  This works for me:

```
string testString = "Hello World!";
System.IO.Fakes.ShimStreamReader.AllInstances.ReadToEnd = reader => testString;
```

For issue 2, I don't believe you can Shim a struct.  `DateTime` is really a struct and not a class.  Here is some sample code I tried:

```
public struct TestShimOfStruct
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class TestShimOfClass
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

...

[TestMethod]
public void TestStructAndClass()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        PartialTest.Fakes.ShimTestShimOfClass.AllInstances.YearGet = shimClass => 2015;
        PartialTest.Fakes.ShimTestShimOfStruct.AllInstances.YearGet = shimClass => 2015;
    }
}
```

The TestMethod shows this error in VisualStudio.   [image: Failure of struct to Shim]

As you can see, the struct fails while the class succeeds even though there are logically equivalent.